# Runing vue/cli app under docker simple index.html is opened

Tags: docker, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I want to install my @vue/cli 4.0.5 app under docker and I found this package
https://hub.docker.com/r/ebiven/vue-cli
Supposing that is what I need (?) I modified _Docker/docker-compose.yml with

```
web:
    container_name: vtasks_web

    build:
        context: ./web
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

    environment:
        - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
    volumes:
        - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
    ports:
        - 8088:80
    working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}

...

vue_cli:
    container_name: vtasks_vue_cli
    image: ebiven/vue-cli:latest
    volumes:
        - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
    working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
    command: npm install
```

Building the app and next checking logs I do not have errors, also node_modules was created(I removed it priorly):

But entering the bush I run

```
npm run serve
```

command  and it shows :

```
ONE  Compiled successfully in 10065ms                                                                                                                                                                                            4:21:52 PM


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 

  It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
  Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

So I run

```
http://localhost:8088/
```

as in container of web I have 8088:80 set
But in browser I see that index.html  is opened(by title and page content) but not js rendered?

What is valid way ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
Looking at demo at https://github.com/ebiven/docker-vue-cli I see that 
ebiven/docker-vue-cli is used as web container, so removing node_modules directory and I remade my _Docker/docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.5'

services:



    web:
        container_name: vtasks_web

        image: ebiven/vue-cli

        command: npm install
#        command: npm install ; npm run serve  // I GOT ERROR HERE
#        command: npm run serve

        build:
            context: ./web
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data

        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - "8088:80"

        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}


    db:
        container_name: vtasks_db
        image: mysql:5.7.28
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=DockerVTasks
            - MYSQL_USER=docker_user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=4321
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=false
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=321
            - TZ=Europe/Kiev

        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql


    adminer:
      container_name: vtasks_adminer
      image: adminer
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8089:8080
      links:
        - db
```

as result I see :

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build     
Building web
Step 1/6 : FROM php:7.3-apache
 ---> 5af347316d4b
Step 2/6 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y     python     libfreetype6-dev     libwebp-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     libzip-dev     nano     mc     git-core     curl     build-essential     openssl     libssl-dev     libgmp-dev     libldap2-dev     netcat     locate     && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git     && cd node     && git checkout v12.0.0     && ./configure      && make      && make install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b56b2543f6bd
Step 3/6 : RUN npm install cross-env
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f8abda742c47
Step 4/6 : RUN  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> df0636ba5b86
Step 5/6 : RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif && a2enmod rewrite
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 307c9f243f02
Step 6/6 : COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3c733883faaa

Successfully built 3c733883faaa
Successfully tagged ebiven/vue-cli:latest
Recreating vtasks_web ... 
vtasks_db is up-to-date
Recreating vtasks_web
Recreating vtasks_web ... done
serge@athoe:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/VApps/vtasks/_Docker$ docker logs --tail=40  vtasks_web

> node-sass@4.13.0 install /var/www/vtasks_docker_root/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node
Download complete
Binary saved to /var/www/vtasks_docker_root/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
Caching binary to /root/.npm/node-sass/4.13.0/linux-x64-72_binding.node

> core-js@3.6.1 postinstall /var/www/vtasks_docker_root/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /var/www/vtasks_docker_root/node_modules/ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)


> node-sass@4.13.0 postinstall /var/www/vtasks_docker_root/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /var/www/vtasks_docker_root/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1239 packages from 876 contributors and audited 19413 packages in 26.747s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I see node_modules directory is generated, but also I need to run

```
npm run serve
```

after

```
npm install
```

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 2 :**

Modified command as

```
command: bash -c "npm install && npm run serve"
```

I have got next output without errors:

```
$ docker logs --tail=20  vtasks_web
<s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization
<s> [webpack.Progress] 93% asset optimization
<s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after asset optimization
<s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after seal
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting HtmlWebpackPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting CopyPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting
<s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting CopyPlugin
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 10316ms4:36:18 AM

<s> [webpack.Progress] 100% 


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 

  It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
  Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/
```

But which url have I to run ?
On

```
 http://localhost:8080/
```

I got error :

```
 This site can’t be reachedlocalhost 
 refused to connect.
```

I tried to set some code for format :
but I am not sure what they call :

> your container's external mapped port

?

But which syntax have I to use?

**MODIFIED BLOCK  # 3**

Running

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

at my browser I got eror :

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.


Checking logs I see : $ docker logs --tail=40 vtasks_web
<s> [webpack.Progress] 87% after chunk id optimization
<s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record modules
<s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record modules RecordIdsPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record chunks
<s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record chunks RecordIdsPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 88% hashing
<s> [webpack.Progress] 88% after hashing
<s> [webpack.Progress] 88% after hashing HotModuleReplacementPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 89% record hash
<s> [webpack.Progress] 89% module assets processing
<s> [webpack.Progress] 90% chunk assets processing
<s> [webpack.Progress] 90% additional chunk assets processing
<s> [webpack.Progress] 90% additional chunk assets processing HotModuleReplacementPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 91% recording
<s> [webpack.Progress] 91% recording HotModuleReplacementPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 92% additional asset processing
<s> [webpack.Progress] 92% chunk asset optimization
<s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization
<s> [webpack.Progress] 93% asset optimization
<s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after asset optimization
<s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after seal
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting HtmlWebpackPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting CopyPlugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting
<s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting CopyPlugin
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 11638ms12:10:15 PM

<s> [webpack.Progress] 100% 


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 

  It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
  Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

But in my _Docker/docker-compose.yml I have options :

```
ports:
    - "8088:80"
```

Actually I have several docker projects, like :

```
$ docker ps                                                                                                                                                
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES                                                                    
99bc972f0840        ebiven/vue-cli      "docker-php-entrypoi"   32 hours ago        Up 8 minutes                    0.0.0.0:8088->80/tcp     vtasks_web                                                             
fcb6d879effa        adminer             "entrypoint.sh docke"   2 weeks ago         Up 8 minutes                    0.0.0.0:8089->8080/tcp   vtasks_adminer                                                         
b0b81c6587bb        mysql:5.7.28        "docker-entrypoint.s"   2 weeks ago         Restarting (1) 47 seconds ago                            vtasks_db
```

The issue with ports is confusing...

Thanks!

Comment: Pls look MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: Who has installed vue/cli app under docker please share your expierence...

Comment: Pleas look MODIFIED BLOCK  # 3

Comment: The ports format is ‘host:container’, so try ‘8080:8080’ so that you can access you app on port 8080 on your host.

Comment: I try 
http://localhost:8080:8080
OR
localhost:8080:8080
in both cases browser does not open any page,
but opens search

But was it correct as I have : ports:
    - "8088:80"
?

Comment: No, that's what I meant. You need to change the ports value in your docker-compose.yml file to `ports: - "8080:8080"`

Comment: Thanks, with that modification it works. One more question : is there is a way to see console of docker "live" ? Now it looks like that I can see current status only entering :  docker logs --tail=40 vtasks_web
?

Comment: Yes, if you run `docker-compose up` without the `-d` you will see the logs live. Otherwise you can also use `docker logs -f vtasks_web`. As a side-note, I know that setting the command as `"npm install && npm run serve"` worked for you, but I'd really recommend running `npm install` in your Dockerfile instead as in my answer below. Then you won't have to wait for everything to install each time you want to run your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a "named volume" for both the `node_modules` directory and the `dist` directory so that those directories won't be overwritten by your bind mount (this thing: `${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}`).

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/containerizing-a-node-js-application-for-development-with-docker-compose) tutorial explains it better:

> The second is a named volume, `node_modules`. When Docker runs the `npm install` instruction listed in the application `Dockerfile`, `npm` will create a new `node_modules` directory on the container that includes the packages required to run the application. The bind mount we just created will hide this newly created `node_modules` directory, however. Since `node_modules` on the host is empty, the bind will map an empty directory to the container, overriding the new `node_modules` directory and preventing our application from starting. The named `node_modules` volume solves this problem by persisting the contents of the `/home/node/app/node_modules` directory and mounting it to the container, hiding the bind.

To do this you can add two new volumes under the `web` service and add them under `volumes` at the bottom of your `docker-compose.yml` too:

```
web:
    volumes:
        - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        - node_modules:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}/node_modules
        - dist:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}/dist

volumes:
  node_modules:
  dist:
```

I got VueCLI working in Docker with the following files:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install --quiet -g http-server

# install the vue-cli
RUN npm install --quiet --global \
      @vue/cli

# create app directory
RUN mkdir /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json /app/

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . /app/

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# build the app
RUN npm run build
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - dist:/app/dist
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    # uncomment command below to run development version
    # command: "npm run serve"
    command: "http-server dist"

volumes:
  node_modules:
  dist:
```

I ran `docker-compose up` and then my app was available at `http://localhost:8080/`.

After updating your `Dockerfile` for the first time, be sure to rebuild the container, e.g. `docker-compose up --build`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do in my docker-compose files is:

```
command: bash -c "npm install && npm run serve"
```

Comment: Thanks! Pleas look MODIFIED BLOCK  # 2

Comment: Pleas look MODIFIED BLOCK  # 3

Comment: Your vue client is redirecting to 8080, but your docker-compose is redirecting 8088 to 80. Change it for "8080:8080", then you will be able to access it on http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

- First, please check your Dockerfile for vue app. You have to include EXPOSE instruction.
- Then make sure your docker-compose correctly maps your hosting machine port to internal docker port

```
ports:
  - LOCAL_PORT:PORT_YOU_EXPOSED_IN_DOCKERFILE
```